# charles remove query param value

Tags: url-rewriting, charles-proxy

How to remove query param value in charles,but save the query param key?

#### origin

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=charles&key=1`

#### expected

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=&key=1`

I set it in charles rewrite feature to replace query param value, but it can't working. When leave the replace value blank, it only refer the match origin value.

[charles rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TSuN.png)

Comment: can you share what have you tried?

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli i am capturing http request and modify the query param value in an app. The app is a popular short video app in China. But it restrict me from accessing the international version of it.For access that need me to rewrite the query param value to blank.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you Charles understands the blank value on the replace section as a *no change*, so you will have to specify a new value there if you want to get rid of it.

I haven't tested it, but I would suggest you to try using the "&" character, as it is the query param separator your request would end up being something like:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=&&key=1`

which essentially is the same as the one you were looking for:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=&key=1`

It this does work, please let us know.

Comment: Just tried. This doesn't work. The server would receive `title` parameter's value as `"&"`